# How to use imagePullSecrets: [] in Helm 3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm-tls

Helm 3 imagePullSecrets: [] secrete gives an error.

Error: unable to build Kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference: got "string", expected "map"

Answer (score 76):

I use this setup and works fine.

In deployment.yaml

```
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      containers:
```

In values.yaml

```
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

And create secret `regcred` manually using

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

You can find detailed documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Comment: I see, in my ingress-nginx values.yaml I had to put it to top level and not under "controller:". Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add the "- " before name :/

Comment: If you get an error, try tweaking the number right after nindent. The correct value is the number of spaces between the beginning of the line and the first "{"

Answer (score 8):

Specifying the imagePullSecret in your *values.yaml* as:

```yaml
imagePullSecrets: ["yourSecret"]
```

will result in the error that you got. The key info in the error is:

```
got "string", expected "map"
```

The manifest requires a 'map' object for `imagePullSecret'. Which should look like this:

```yaml
imagePullSecrets: [{ name: yourSecret }]
```

Executing:

```bash
helm install --dry-run .\mychart
```

also helps to validate the change:

```bash
COMPUTED VALUES:
...
imagePullSecrets:
- name: yourSecret 
...
```

Answer (score 3):

How to create ImagePullSecret:

https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#creating-image-pull-secrets

Add to deployment:

```
spec:
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```